# Firebase Notification. Subscribe a topic with different apps in the same project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have a one project created in firebase with several applications. Each application has a different package. [image: One Project]

The first app:

```
 package="com.example.miguelprades.notificacacionesfirebase2"
```

can subscribe to topics ( and create them). I use the folowing code

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("Noticias2");
```

But the second application:

```
package = "com.miguelprades.bandolero"
```

cannot subscribe to the topics created by the first app, and cannot create a new topics. However, I can send notifications to both appications with the console.

[image: Send notificatios via packages]

My question is, How I can create a topic with the second app?. If it is not posible, How I can send notifications to a concrete package like I make in the console?.

I use the following code for send nofications, this code work's maybe it is helpful for someone.

```
public function SendNotificationFirebase($titulo ,$mensaje,$paquete,$serverKey){
    $message = array("message" => "$titulo");
    $notification = array("message" => $titulo, "body" => $mensaje, "icon" => "ic_launcher");
    $url = 'http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'to' => "/topics/Noticias3",
        'data' => $message,
        'notification' => $notification);


    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = '.$serverKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);           
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```